# Algorithm mcrypt AES for Android?

Tags: android, mcrypt

I need to implement a reversible encryption key algorithm such as mcrypt AES or use ready-made libraries.

For example, I have:

```
String pass = "12345";
String salt = "XgKHRfTnvytMLPgTDE";
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, unfortunately your question does not demonstrate any attempt of prior research. In order to get a good response, it is advised you should show evidence you have attempted to solve the problem, either in code or otherwise, before asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reversible AES encryption, you can use [this code](https://snipt.net/raw/ee573b6957b7416f28aa560ead71c3a2/?nice).

But I see you are trying to encrypt password, which is considered to be a bad idea. If you need to store user passwords, use **hashing algorithms** - I highly suggest [SHA-512](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) with [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) (50 000 derivations should be enough).

Comment: php programmer wants zashirovat password, and then all the md5 hash in using salt. Is this normal practice?

Comment: md5 is a weak hashing algorithm and is strictly not recommended for hashing user passwords.

Comment: But using salt (which should be unique for every user) is a good practice.

Comment: What do you recommend?
 I need to pass the username and password to transfer to the server. What format is best for sending json object to the server login and password. 
Thanks for the help:)

Comment: In this case, you should encrypt password in app and send it to the server through POST request. Here, you decrypt it, hash it and compare it to the original hashed password in your database.